# Passing additional arguments to process

Tags: c#, process

I have this piece of code:

```
string name = "mark";
string strCmdText2 = @"/C app\bin\tekstar --config test.txt";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText2);
```

when it executes, there is a command prompt and it's waiting for a text to be entered like this:

```
Enter username:
```

So the question is: How can I pass the string name to that command prompt? What's the complete code so that the program will automatically pass the string to the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `RedirectStandardIn` property in `ProcessStartInfo` to `true`.

You can then send input to the program by writing to the `In` property of the resulting `Process` object.